# Solution to Linear Nonhomogeneous Differential Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider system:

$x'(t) = 3x(t) +e^{3t}$

$y'(t) = 2x(t) -y(t) -2z(t)$

$z'(t) = 3x(t) +6y(t) +6z(t)$

by first finding 3 lin. indep. solutions to the homogeneous Vector ODE: $x'(t) = C x(t)$

then constructing the fundamental matrix $M(t|0)$

and hence finding the solution for $x(t)$ , $y(t)$ , $z(t)$ given , $x(0)=1$, $y(0)=0$, $z(0)=0$

I have found eigenvalues $2,3,3$ and corresponding eingenvectors
$$(0,-2,3), (2,1,0)$$
I am stuck finding the last eigenvector. as the eigenvalue of 3 has a multiplicty 2

Comment: fair enough, well for the first bit (vector ODE solution), i found eigenvalues of 2,3,3. and so then the eigen vectors (respectively) {0 -2 3} , (2 1 0) , and then im stuck on finding the next one as the eigenvalue of 3 has a multiplicty of 2. so not sure what to do there.  but once i find that i should be able to form the Fundamental Matrix and see how i go from there

Comment: You have a Matrix $A\in\mathbb{R}^{3\times 3}$ and want to find two EVs to an eigenvalue, right?

Comment: yup, in our notes it shows a bit of theory where for a eigenvalue with multiplicty 2 , you find a second eigenvector from the first just multiplying by the variable, in my case 't' .

Comment: Yes, but you need l.i. vectors, so $tv$ will not suffice, as $v, tv$ are l.d. ;-) Find a basis of 
$$\ker A-2 {\rm id} = \langle v, ? \rangle$$

Comment: You are not looking for an eigenvalue; you are looking for a basis for the nullspace of $A-3I$. That nullspace has dimension 2. Do you know how to find a basis for the nullspace of a matrix?

Comment: would it be ker A- 3id = <v,?> as the eigenvalue concerned is 3

Comment: Gerry, i did once, forgotten for now, enlighten me :P

Comment: If you want to get someone's attention, you have to put @ before the name.

Answer (score 4):

From your system, we have:

$$A = \begin{bmatrix}3 & 0 & 0\\2 & -1 & -2 \\ 3 & 6 & 6\end{bmatrix}$$

The characteristic polynomial is:

$$-\lambda^3+8 \lambda^2-21 \lambda+18 = -(\lambda-3)^2 (\lambda-2)$$

We have the eigenvalues: $\lambda_1 = 2, \lambda_2 = 3, \lambda_3 = 3$ (a single and double algebraic multiplicity).

- For the first eigenvalue, we set up and solve $[A - 2I]v_1 = 0$, which leads to the eigenvector $v_1 = (0,-2,3)$.
- For the second eigenvalue, we set up and solve $[A - 3I]v_2 = 0$, which leads to a RREF of:

$$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0\\0 & 1 & \frac{1}{2} \\ 0 & 0  & 0\end{bmatrix}v_2 = 0$$

This gives us a second eigenvector of $v_2 = (0, -1, 2)$ (of course other choices were possible.) However, the RREF does not admit a second eigenvector, so we need to find a generalized eigenvector.

One approach to this (did you learn why in class and there are many other ways), is to set up and solve $[A - 3 I]v_3 = v_2$.

$$\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 & 0\\2 & -4 & 2 \\ 3 & 6  & 3\end{bmatrix}v_3 = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ -1 \\ 2 \end{bmatrix}$$

This gives us a RREF of:

$$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 \\0 & 1 & \dfrac{1}{2}  \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}v_3 = \begin{bmatrix} \dfrac{1}{12} \\ \dfrac{7}{24} \\ 0\end{bmatrix}$$

This leads to a generalized eigenvector of:

$$v_3 = \left(\dfrac{1}{12}, \dfrac{7}{24}, 0\right)$$

Now, you can also do the same using the basis of the nullspace, so you might want to understand that.

It is worth mentioning that  you can reduce one equation given that $x'$ is uncoupled from the other two equations. You can solve for $x(t)$ and then substitute into the other two equations, so you only have a $2x2$ to deal with.

Lastly, note and do not forget that your system is of the form:

$$X'[t] = AX[t] + F[t]$$

Comment: Greetings! Hope you had a great day!